# How to change ionic alert element

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I'm new in ionic, I try to change alert element scss but it doesn't work.

`list.html`

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="dept_title" style="color: white; display:none" #sel > 
  <ion-option  *ngFor="let data of dept_data" value="{{data.deptid}}">
    {{data.deptid}}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

`list.ts`

```
selectOpen(sel){
  sel.open();
}
```

`list.scss`

```
page-list {
  ion-option {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply css to ion-Option. Instead you have to apply css to interface type you have taken, Here by default they gives `<ion-option interface="alert"> </ion-option>`. 
So you have to apply CSS by  AlertController CSS commands you can follow step given below .

I will prefer ionic official CSS Commands.

1) Go to AlertController doc page of oficial web site of ionic . https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

2) At the bottom of the page you can find an option for CSS as 'Material Design'

3) Pick CSS command from there according to your need. and apply it.

- In your case you can apply :

  **$alert-md-background-color : #808080**

You can apply it globally by putting it in '`src\theme\variable.scc`' file 
OR
You can apply it on your particular page by putting it in your `"list.scss"` page.

Hope it will help you . Thanks